# C# - two ways for calling this generic method. Is there any difference in?

Tags: c#, generics

I use this code to load a MDIchild form from within another MDIchild form. I'm learning still how to use generics in my method so when I get my method to work finally with the help of the people here I end u with two slightly different codes which in my case do the job the same way. So my question is - is it coincidence that those two variations do the same job or there's just no difference between the two approaches.

So here is version 1:

```
protected void LoadAForm<T>(ref T sendTo) where T : Form
{
    MainForm frm = this.MdiParent as MainForm;
    if (frm != null)
    {
        sendTo = SingletonFormProvider.GetInstance<T>(frm, true);
        sendTo.MdiParent = frm;
        sendTo.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        sendTo.Show();
    }
}
```

And here is version 2:

```
protected void LoadAForm<T>(ref T sendTo) where T : Form
{
    MainForm frm = this.MdiParent as MainForm;
    T temp;
    if (frm != null)
    {
        temp= SingletonFormProvider.GetInstance<T>(frm, true);
        temp.MdiParent = frm;
        temp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        temp.Show();
    }
}
```

So is there (if any difference) to use the `T temp` instantiation or it's just the same thing?

Comment: what's the question? where are you using `sendTo` in second version. And if they're similar, explain HOW

Comment: You **never** use `sendTo` in the second method, unless you set `sendTo` to temp.

Comment: Both methods are doing the same job either using `sendTo` directly or declaring `T temp` and using it. I just want to know if there's any difference b/w those two ways of doing the job.

Comment: @Leron - the only difference is for the *caller* of this method. In the second version, the `sendTo` parameter they provide is unaltered, and so they won't be able to use it after the call completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that in the 2nd scenario, your newly created and shown form will not be available outside LoadAForm in your sendTo param.
The first method seems to work correctly, accomplishing what it was intended for by passing a reference parameter to it.

Another natural way is to return the newly created as a function return value form instead of returning it throug a ref'ed parameter.

LATER EDIT:
Frankly said, as Henk Holterman said, you are misusing the ref usage.

By the way, if you still want to pass a parameter to that method, use **out** instead of **ref**!

Ok, this is what I mean: declare your method like this:

```
protected T LoadAForm<T>() where T : Form
```

and return the form you just instantiated. Simple.

Comment: Ok, thanks, let me try. But isn't it better to use out anyways. I just read some info and it seems like a solution?

Comment: out and ref are always solution depending what you need. but in this case the best is to implement it the way I showed you. but if you strongly want that parameter, ref should be replaced with out.

Comment: No, I did `protected T LoadAForm<T>() where T : Form` and it works exactly how I wanted. Gonna accept it since it's really the best solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: to make it simpler to understand, you should use ref if you need the value of that parameter inside your function; if you just want to return a value through a parameter, then out is what needs to be used

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with generics. It is about the (mis)use of `ref` parameters.

> So is there (if any difference) to use the T temp instantiation or it's just the same thing?

Inside this method there is no difference. But after the call, the argument passed to 'sendTo' will be changed by version 1 and stay the same when using version 2.

Which one is correct cannot be guessed from this piece of code.

Comment: Ok, I asked this question because the both scenarios were suggested by people who has much more experience than me. If they to the same job (and it seems so) which one is correct or the both are not very good?

Comment: `            Shoes shoe = new Shoes();
            LoadAForm<Shoes>(ref shoe);` that;s how I call it

Comment: @Leron Check my answer, first is better than the second because at least uses the sendTo parameter, but both lack in good practices. Just let the method return the form you just created.

Comment: @Henk Holterman if ref is removed there is no reason for sendTo. If there's no reason for sendTo, he should just return back the newly created form and he's fine

Comment: No need for `ref` there. On the contrary.

Comment: @Leron By the way, if you still want to pass a parameter, use out instead of ref

Comment: I need to pass the exact form that I want to be shown. No I first make an instance and pass it to the method. It would be nice if I can just pass the class

Comment: You misunderstood. I mean, you should declare the function like this: protected T LoadAForm<T>() where T : Form